# Intuition for recursively looking at Eigen Vectors of the eigen vector matrix of a matrix A?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to understand if there is some intuition to the idea of eigen vectors of a normalized eigen vector matrix of a matrix itself. 
To elaborate, let A be a n x n square matrix, we know that A can be decomposed to:

$ A = S \Lambda S^{-1} $ where $\Lambda$  is the diagonal matrix with eigenvalues as its entries and S is the normalized eigenvector matrix, with eigen vectors as its columns. Although these eigen vectors are not unique, but they define a direction, eigenspace for each eigenvalue.

Moreover, is there some pattern/intuition I can expect when I recursively start looking at eigenvectors of the eigenvector matrix itself. How does the eigenvector matrix (or eigen space) traverse the space $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ as we recursively setup such a matrices.

I tried looking at a simple case below:

Let A = $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and look at the eigen vector decomposition $ A = S \Lambda S^{-1} $below:

Here S = $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\1 & -1\end{bmatrix} \text{ and } S^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}2 & \frac{1}2 \\\frac{1}2 & \frac{-1}2\end{bmatrix} \text{ and }\Lambda =  \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$

Now if I look at eigen decomposition (without normalization) of eigenvector matrix $ S = P \Omega P^{-1}$, we get:

P = $\begin{bmatrix}1+\sqrt{2} & 1-\sqrt{2} \\1 & 1\end{bmatrix} \text{ and } \Omega =  \begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{2} & 0 \\0 & -\sqrt{2}\end{bmatrix}$ and so on...

Is there any connection between eigenvectors of A and eigenvectors of S or any interesting behavior as we repeatedly look at such eigenvectors recursively? (Although both seem to be orthogonal to each other, but when I do one level deep, that orthogonality disappears).

Is there any such thing or I am just looking at something random?

Clearly Identity matrix  has all vectors as eigenvectors and hence we can create any random matrix as eigenvector matrix, but that might be some special case. What kind of path is traversed by EigenVector matrices(think as vectors). Do they converge?, may be in some cases? etc.

I hope the question is not vague. I tried searching online but could not find anything.

Adding some modifications based on the feedback from @Arthur in the comment section:

Since the Eigenvectors are not unique, especially when the multiplicity of eigenvalues is more than 1, because we could chose infinite set of eigen vectors for an eigen matrix. Although there might be some patterns here, but let us restrict ourselves to matrix A with real and distinct eigen values, which ensures that we get unique unit eigen vectors (directions). Now can we claim to have some patterns in the set of eigen values and eigen vectors as we look recursively at the normalized eigen vector matrices.

Comment: Each $A$ has many possible $S$'s. For instance, for your example $A$, any invertible $2\times 2$ matrix will work.

Comment: @Arthur: Agreed but their directions are constant. Does the direction of recursive eigen vectors show some interesting pattern?

Comment: But they aren't. A different choice for $S$ will completely change what any possible $P$ might look like. And as I also tried to say, some times you can't even guarantee that the directions are constant, as any eigenvalue with higher multiplicity will give you a lot of freedom of choice for the eigenvectors. In particular, for _your example $A$_, **any invertible matrix** works as $S$.

Comment: @Arthur: Understood...Thanks. 
What if I want to study some specific cases where it might make sense to look for some patterns. For e.g. When we have real and distinct eigen values for A, thus ensuring unique eigenvector directions, can we be sure that all recursive eigenvalues will be real/distinct, and eigenvectors will be unique as well?

Comment: @Arthur: What do you mean by : "for your example A, any invertible matrix works as  S"
For the set of eigenvalues of A in the diagonal matrix, I cannot use just any invertible matrix.E.g. consider the matrix P = [1 2, 3 4]. Doing P * Lamda * P_inverse does not produce A. I am not looking at just diagonalizing A, but only via eigen vector decomposition.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your $A$, thought you were using the identity matrix. Apparently I haven't had enough sleep.

Comment: @Arthur: It is my mistake. I think you replied very quickly before I even had the chance to fix that typo when I submitted the question. :)

Comment: One thing to add: We can show that if Original matrix A has real distinct eigenvalues (all with multiplicity 1), then all recursive eigenvector matrices will have distinct eigen values of their own. therefore looking recursively at unit eigenvectors of such matrices, all of them will be linearly independent (not sure if this is interesting though).